# OpenCV - Measuring distance between two edges

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to measure the distance (in pixels) between two edges.
Following are the images I used and the link to code I used.

**Images** :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In program 1 : [Program1](http://pastebin.com/VNdhyYuU)

I scanned the particular row of the image `Mat` from 0 to cols. i.e. along one scan line. In this case I obtained the location of white pixels i.e. edge pixels correctly .

In program 2 : [Program2](http://pastebin.com/uJNwr4ka)

I scanned the particular row of the image `Mat` from middle , i.e. I measure from middle to right direction of row till cols and again from middle to 0th column of the row. In this case I get erroneous value while getting the location of white pixel i.e. edge pixel.

Can you please suggest me what’s wrong in the code or if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I did not go through your code. But if you want to measure the distance between two edges which are not parallel, I would suggest taking the distances between them for each rows and taking an average. And maybe the erroneous values, you are getting is because of multiple edges. So here is what you can possibly do,

1. Start from row 0, col 0
2. Get white pixel, store current column. (cur_loc = xxx )
3. Find the next white pixel ( new_loc = yyy ), measure diff, put it in a table. Mark this pixel as the start pixel (cur_loc = new_loc ) and search for the next until you reach the end 
   of the columns.
4. Reset cur_loc and new_loc and start all over again.